# How to generate gridview binded barcode to pdf?

Tags: c#, itext

I have grid which binds some barcodes from databas. This barcodes I want to generate in pdf. How can I do this? Sorry I dont have any idea how to do this so there is no sample code to show. My gridview name "GrdBarcode".Please help me.Below is my grid with barcodes

```
  <asp:GridView ID="grdBarcode" CssClass="table"   
 OnRowDataBound="grdBarcode_RowDataBound" AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
 GridLines="None" runat="server">
 <Columns>
 <asp:TemplateField>
<ItemTemplate>
 <table style="width:100%">
 <tr>
 <p>Date:<asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label5" Text='<%#Eval("Date") %>'>    
 </asp:Label>   </p></td>
 <td align="center"></td> <td><p>No Of QP: <asp:Label runat="server"   
 ID="Label6" Text='<%#Eval("NoOfQP") %>'></asp:Label></p>
 <p>Time: <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label7" Text='<%#Eval("Timing") %>'>
 </asp:Label></p>
 <p>Durations: <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label8"  
Text='<%#Eval("Duration") %>'></asp:Label>)</p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="3" align="center">
<asp:DataList ID="datalistBarcode"  RepeatColumns="3"  
RepeatDirection="Horizontal" GridLines="None" 
OnItemDataBound="datalistBarcode_ItemDataBound"  runat="server">
<ItemTemplate> <asp:Label ID="lblBarCode" runat="server"   
Text='<%#Eval("BarCode") %>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>
<table class="table">
<tr> <td >
<asp:Panel ID="pnlBarCode" HorizontalAlign="center"  runat="server">
</asp:Panel>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center"><asp:Label ID="lblStudCode" runat="server" 
Text='<%#Eval("StudCode") %>'></asp:Label>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</ItemTemplate>
 </asp:DataList>
</td>
</tr>
 </table>
</ItemTemplate></asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

[image]

I tried like elow mentioned methode.but it shows error `Document has no pages`

```
 protected void btnPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow row in grdBarcode.Rows)
        {
            DataList dl = (DataList)row.FindControl("datalistBarcode");
            string attachment = "attachment; filename=Article.pdf";
            Response.ClearContent();
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment);
            Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            StringWriter stw = new StringWriter();
            HtmlTextWriter htextw = new HtmlTextWriter(stw);
            dl .DataBind();
            dl .RenderControl(htextw);
            Document document = new Document();
            PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, Response.OutputStream);
            document.Open();
            StringReader str = new StringReader(stw.ToString());
            HTMLWorker htmlworker = new HTMLWorker(document);
            htmlworker.Parse(str);
            document.Close();
            Response.Write(document);
            Response.End();
        }
```

Comment: Bar code strings or images? what Pdf library are you using to generate the Pdf file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you need a grid, it is best to use a `PdfPTable`.

If you don't have the barcodes yet, you can create them with iText or iTextSharp. Take a look at the [Barcodes](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/tables/Barcodes) example for inspiration:

```
public void createPdf(String dest) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    Document document = new Document();
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(dest));
    document.open();
    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(4);
    table.setWidthPercentage(100);
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        table.addCell(createBarcode(writer, String.format("%08d", i)));
    }
    document.add(table);
    document.close();
}

public static PdfPCell createBarcode(PdfWriter writer, String code) throws DocumentException, IOException {
    BarcodeEAN barcode = new BarcodeEAN();
    barcode.setCodeType(Barcode.EAN8);
    barcode.setCode(code);
    PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(barcode.createImageWithBarcode(writer.getDirectContent(), BaseColor.BLACK, BaseColor.GRAY), true);
    cell.setPadding(10);
    return cell;
}
```

For some C# code on creating barcodes, see:

- [Barcode with Text Under using ItextSharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4917809/barcode-with-text-under-using-itextsharp)
- [Add itextsharp barcode image to PdfPCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19412948/add-itextsharp-barcode-image-to-pdfpcell)
- [generate barcode in pdf when using itextsharp to build the pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17495163/generate-barcode-in-pdf-when-using-itextsharp-to-build-the-pdf)
- ...

If you already have the images with the barcodes, you can still use a table, but then the question should be *How do I organize images inside a table?*

That is answered in questions such as:

- [How to add an image to a table cell in iTextSharp using webmatrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16589044/how-to-add-an-image-to-a-table-cell-in-itextsharp-using-webmatrix)
- [Image auto resizes in PdfPCell with iTextSharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3022468/image-auto-resizes-in-pdfpcell-with-itextsharp)
- [itextsharp and images sizes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8234062/itextsharp-and-images-sizes)
- [Putting several images next to each other in a pdfcell with itextsharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8485600/putting-several-images-next-to-each-other-in-a-pdfcell-with-itextsharp)
- [iTextSharp: How to resize an image to fit a fix size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9412504/itextsharp-how-to-resize-an-image-to-fit-a-fix-size)
- [Image resizes when inserted in PdfCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15741980/image-resizes-when-inserted-in-pdfcell)
- ...

Comment: I have a doubt,I have getting barcode in datalist. Can I iterates each barcodes and add the value into pdfcell using foreach loop ?

Comment: Define *barcode in datalist*. Are you talking about a list of images that you can use in a loop? In that case: yes, loop over that list and create a `PdfPCell` for every image and add those cells to a `PdfPTable`.

Comment: I cannot call the datalist control in my foreach loop. See my updated answer

Comment: @SemilSebastian I don't understand the question. The reason I don't understand the question, is that I have no clue as to which format is used for `<asp:Label ID="lblStudCode" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("StudCode") %>'></asp:Label>`.

Comment: Hmm... You're using `HTMLWorker`. As explained in many answers to many questions, `HTMLWorker` has been abandoned a long time ago. `HTMLWorker` is no longer supported and no questions about `HTMLWorker` are being answered anymore.

Comment: Oh I see. Then i wil use looping method

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82961/discussion-between-semil-sebastian-and-bruno-lowagie).

Comment: I solved my problem eventhough I have another doubt that I have posted as a separate question. Please have a look.You can help me

Answer (score -1):

There is 2 ways to do this depending on the datatype you have in the database.

If you have it stored  as a string :

> - Create your Crystal Report
> - Drag the binded field onto the report
> - change the field font to the barcode font you have (usually shipped with wand reader)
> - Export the report to PDF

If you have it stored as an image :

> - Create your crystal report
> - Grab the image data from database as `Image` object
> - put the `Image` object into a `MemoryStream`
> - convert the `MemoryStream` to `Byte[]`
> - add a column to your crystal report data to be of type `Byte[]`
> - store the value into this column
> - Drag the new data field onto the report and it will be an image
> - Export the report to PDF

Comment: This is a Crystal report answer to a question tagged as an iTextSharp question.

Comment: @ Bruno Lowagie, any idea :)

Comment: @Franck That's irrelevant: the OP doesn't mention Crystal Reports.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie he doesn't mention `String` either so does that prevent people from adding answer that make use of the string object ?

Comment: @Franck You don't mean that, do you? The `string` object is part of C#; Crystal Reports is a separate product.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie Feel happier if i say to use Microsoft reporting instead ? It's not a separate product and give the same exact result.

Comment: @Franck persuade the OP to add the tag crystal-reports and your answer will no longer be off-topic. Right now, the tags say C# and iTextSharp.

Comment: @Franck Also: you are missing *context*. The OP has posted several questions about iTextSharp and tables in iTextSharp in the last couple of days (http://stackoverflow.com/q/31152874 http://stackoverflow.com/q/31263533 http://stackoverflow.com/q/31283302 ). His question isn't tagged "iTextSharp" by accident.